# Dynamically change plane height in babylonjs

Tags: babylonjs

I created a plane by using

this.plane = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreatePlane("plane", { width: 0.5, height: 10 }, scene, true);

and then I try to modify the plane height in rendering, but the height is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for scaling. Here is the link to [Babylon.js Scaling](https://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/Position,_Rotation,_Scaling). Essentially, you do

```
objectName.scaling.x = 1.50 //This is a scaling multiplier (you can substitute x, y, and z)
//Or, if you want to scale in more than one direction, you can use a vector3
objectName.scaling = new Babylon.Vector3(1.5,.5, 2)
```

This should let you dynamically change the dimensions of your object. If you wanted the make the change visibly noticeable (instead of jumping straight to the correct size) you could also add an animation to it.